# Assistance building a computer. Check my build and needs

Tags: pc

I need assistance in building my own computer. Budget is not a problem. To understand what i need, i do the following.

- Run Ubuntu OS
- Run Multiple virual machines at one time (often two,
  kali linux and windows 10 , i assume i need multiple cores and big memory, 64gb?)
- Run a Ethereum Node (not mining tho, i assume this takes up networking (wifi) and memory)
- Run Adobe Cloud programs in the windows 10 VM (takes a ton of my
  recourses, memory and more cores i guess?)
- Will still need to connect via wifi on desktop temporarily, but i assume i can just use a usb wifi moduel, is that correct?

I tried to build a computer on PCPartPicker, but i just do not know enough to make a good decision. I am familiar with overclocking if its recommended, and wont have a problem doing so.

Can someone help assist in marking or guiding me to what i need? Budget is not a problem, but id like to keep it under 5,000 USD.

Additional question,

- Do i need a cache in my SSD?
- Pick me a Video Card, i have no clue
- Is anything i have completely unnecessary and be replaced with something much cheaper for nearly the same performance?

  **This is my current build, please inform me of better options and recommendations**
  [enter link description here](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/XGYvM8)

Comment: Do you need the 10-bit color output from the Adobe programs (is for a professional display)?

Comment: No i will not, i dont believe i will. I only use adobe programs for web development purposes such as creating logos or website adjustments in dreamweaver. But i do plan on purchasing a high def/professional monitor.

Comment: I updated the build link, im constantly researching to see what i need. I dont have a clue if im going to need a intensive GPU not. VM's will use RAM and CPU i believe.

Comment: We could really need more details of what you'll be working on. If you're using Photoshop, what sized images, etc. You might also get a better response if you break your question into smaller ones that deal with one component at a time. I suggest starting with the case, with any requirements that you might have (mounting for radiators, quietness, size, GPU length, etc)